# Access Denied in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am getting 'Access Denied Error' while running my project on android studio. How can I resolve this issue?

Detailed Error Message:

> C:\Users\sharm\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplicationMovieTicketBookingApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageDebug\tmp\debug\zip-cache\androidResources (Access is denied)

[image]

Comment: If you are using *nix, try running Android Studio using root user & if you are using windows, try using Admin user.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Frist You Add Android Sdk Location to  Environment Variables

After You can access any location .

you can find youtube how to add sdk path to environment variables.

#Android_studio

Comment: Brother, I tried to add SDK path to enviroment variables  as told in the YouTube Video, but unfortunately the error hasn't been resolved . Kindly try to provide some other solution. I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: @Vaibhav Have you got solution for this? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: The another reason for the error "Access is denied" might be the Antivirus program installed on your device. Your Antivirus might be restricting the Android studio to behave properly. For this you can change the permissions on your Antivirus app. Because in my case my license for antivirus expired few days ago, so my Android studio is now working fine. Hope this helps!